# Javascript call java method doesn't work immediately after the page was loaded in webview?

Tags: javascript, java, webview

Here is my problem, I want to call Java method like window.jsBridge which is defined in java via:

```
CustomChromeClient client = new CustomChromeClient(
   "jsBridge", WebCallJsFunction.class);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(client);

mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

and in my html:

```
<body>
</script>
  document.write(window.jsBridge.getSomething())
</script>
</body>
```

The page will show nothing, because window.jsBridge is undefined, but if I chage it to this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.write(window.jsBridge.getSomething())
}, 500)
```

the page will write the correct thing. I guess the reason is that the java method: `mWebView.setWebChromeClient(client)` is executing with the js in text.html **at the same time**, and when the js run:  `document.write(window.jsBridge.getSomething())` then java code has **not** executed completed, am I right? So how to solve this problem?